# React Native- loading app parts on demand?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval, react-native

My app consists of 5000+ views, and my boss wants those views to be served from the backend. So I need to create a app/shell in react native, that will be installed via app store, and that will know how to fetch those 5000+ views on demand (as user taps on navigation links). I wrote a prototype that fetches those views and runs them using eval() function. My question, is there a better way than using eval() to execute code I downloaded from the server? Because I know that eval() has some limitations and is not performant as having the code executed the regular way.

Also, I'm using global objects to communicate between the react-native shell part and the new code that I downloaded and executed with eval(), everything that I need to share between the two is placed on the global window object. Has anyone a suggestion how to do this better?

Thanks.

Comment: all executed js coming from a server goes through `eval` when it hits the client...

Comment: do those 5000+ views have similar layout and functionality of some kind?

Comment: @dandavis, currently I'm doing that, but I'm not happy with that solution

Comment: @AakashSigdel, yes, they are significantly different